Setting up liquibase.properties is not working
I have setup liquibase in .gradle like
liquibase {
  activities {
    main {
      changelogFile "./cfg/liquibase/changelog.xml"
      url "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=test;queryTimeout=120;lockTimeout=15000;trustServerCertificate=true"
      username "user"
      password "test"
    }
  }
}

which is working fine.
I would like to move that to a liquibase.properties file. In .gradle I did
liquibase {
  activities {
    main{
      defaultsFile "../liquibase.properties"
    }
  }
}

and in liquibase.properties I did:
changelogFile="./cfg/liquibase/changelog.xml"
url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=test;queryTimeout=120;lockTimeout=15000;trustServerCertificate=true"
username="user"
password="pass"

Trying to do liquibase update I get this error:
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver class was not specified and could not be determined from the url ("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=test;queryTimeout=120;lockTimeout=15000;trustServerCertificate=true")

I veryfied picking up the correct liquibase.properties file by setting up different urls. At the moment I do not know what to do. Any ideas?
